# Do I store unique items as an object or array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am designing a small online shop application and using MongoDB where I have an order table which is supposed to contain items.

Every item has a unique attribute `code`.

Do I store items in the database as an object, which makes searching very simple: `items[code]`

```
items : {
  "AR2"   : { quantity : 50 },
  "LS569" : { quantity : 30 },
}
```

Or do I store it as an array (and search for an item using loops):

```
items : [
  { code : "AR2",   quantity : 50 },
  { code : "LS569", quantity : 30 }
]
```

Which is better, and what are possible drawbacks and advantages of each method, when retrieving data from database?

Comment: it's personal preference. and would be closed.

Comment: It will help http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them

Comment: @AkshayJ That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Juhana It helps when to use array and when to go for object.Specifying pros and cons for both

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic problem with the first example. If you want to find documents that contain "AR2" then you have to query like this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "items.AR2": { "$exists": true }})
```

And if you just wanted to show only items that are "AR2" then you do this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "items.AR2": { "$exists": true }},{ "items.AR2": 1 })
```

So Uck! for lack of a better term.

You **cannot** use an "index" to speed searches and you **cannot** aggregate across documents for "AR2" or others in a simple way since MongoDB operators cannot traverse the keys of documents in that way.

Doing useful things with such a structure usually means coding with JavaScript methods and "brute force" matching in your collection. All of which is Bad.

Also "data as keynames" is bad for databases. You should have "data" as "data" as shown in the second example.

Where you can use an index:

```js
db.collection.ensuteIndex({ "items.code": 1 })

db.collection.find({ "items.code": "AR2" })
```

Which is fast.

And you can add up all "AR2" very easily and fast as well:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "items.code": "AR2" } },
    { "$unwind": "$items" },
    { "$match": { "items.code": "AR2" } },
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "sum": { "$sum": "$items.quantity" } }
])
```

So indexes an native processing functions that can work more efficiently on your data than the other required JavaScript manipulation you would have to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Are you sure that no two items will have the same code? In that case, you might get away with the first option of using an object. I don't think the performance differences will be that significant.

If you use the first example, you'll be able to type `item = items[code]` to access an item with a particular code.

But let's say you want to add a field called 'name', and look up an item with a particular name. In the first case, this would be tricky, but in the second case, it's a simple `var item = items.where(name: name);`

Or maybe you want to ensure each item has a unique name. It would be much easier to add an index in the second case (I think some of the other answers have talked about this).

In general, a good strategy is to use arrays for when you have a *collection* of things (like items), and use objects with properties for, well properties.